# Any problems of my php query?

Tags: php, sql

Here is my code.

```
<?php

$a = bacon;
$b = 20;
$c = 30;

$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root',''); 
mysql_select_db("test", $link);

$sql = "UPDATE share SET price=".
         PrepSQL($b) . ", place=" .
         PrepSQL($c) . ", time=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where num=1 and RID=(select IID from ingredient where Ingredient='" . PrepSQL($a) . "')";

mysql_query($sql);

function PrepSQL($value)
{
    // Stripslashes
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }

    // Quote
    $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";

    return($value);
}
?>
```

I found the code above cannot update the DB table.
But, if I change the where condition to 
where num=1 and RID=(select IID from ingredient where Ingredient=**'bacon'**)"
then, everything works fine.
So, any problems of my code?
Thanks so much!

Comment: try this see what the error `mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());` or `echo` the `$sql` and see if the sql is correct and for your knowledge `mysql_*` if depreciated in php 5.5 you have to use `mysqli_*` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery

```
"[...] (select IID from ingredient where Ingredient='" . PrepSQL($a) . "')"
```

should really be

```
"[...] (select IID from ingredient where Ingredient=" . PrepSQL($a) . ")"
```

since the call to `PrepSQL` already adds the single quotes for you.

Also, please avoid using `mysql_*` php function since they're now deprecated! For further options see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

EDIT:

also, you have a probably undefined `bacon` constant, should be `"bacon"` instead.

Comment: Thanks. But even I changed the code, the query still cannot update the table.

Comment: Have you tried `echo`ing the result of `mysql_error()` after the query? Also please show us the updated query, and you could also try `echo`ing it before sending it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

If it's supposed to be a string, then it needs quotes around it.

```
$a = 'bacon';
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use :

```
<?php

$a = "bacon";
$b = 20;
$c = 30;

$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root',''); 
mysql_select_db("test", $link);

$sql = "UPDATE share SET price=".
         PrepSQL($b) . ", place=" .
         PrepSQL($c) . ", time=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where num=1 and RID=(select IID from ingredient where Ingredient='" . PrepSQL($a) . "')";

mysql_query($sql);

function PrepSQL($value)
{
    // Stripslashes
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }

    // Quote
    $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";

    return($value);
}
?>
```